# How to put button next to Image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, position, css-position

On my asp.net page I have some `Update Pannel`. In order to avoid problems with asynchronous postback I have to put my `Print Button` outside the pannel, but all other labels and Images for my buttons still inside this pannel, so I want to control style of page in CSS to place my `btnPrint` right next to `image1`.

Here is my Page Layout:

```
<div id="Toolbar">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateToolbar" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="   Months: "></asp:Label>&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonth" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="   Year: "></asp:Label>&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <b id="buttonWrap">>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/DefRefreshBtn.png" Width="15"
                    Height="20" />&nbsp;
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click1">Refresh</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/DefPrintBtn.png" Width="27"
                    Height="20" />
            </b>                   
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPrint" runat="server" onclick="btnPrint_Click" CssClass="printBtn">Print</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Currently, I'm using this `CssClass="printBtn"`:

```
.printBtn
{
    position: relative;
    top: -23px;
    right: -700px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But this hard coding could cause the issue in different browsers. Is it any way to specify in CSS my button to be right next to `image1`?

Comment: Actual output HTML required.

Comment: show us the actual render for html, please dont use `asp` codes as for people that are designers who wants to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use absolute positioning.  A better solution is to keep it inside the UpdatePanel but make the print button do a full postback. You can do this with a PostBackTrigger

Here is example of how to do a full post back
[Force certain controls to do a full postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232970/force-certain-controls-to-do-a-full-postback)

Comment: This should have been a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I disagree....it's a suggestion. You don't know anything about the actual HTML so absolute position might not be appropriate.

Comment: I agree that this is suggestion, but this is helpful. I found an example of how to solve my problem. I'll edit this and accept it. Sorry for HTML guys=)